# Php : How can I make values that have been saved in a table appear on the page as being checked?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have a table in my app, `contacts`, where a user (`user_id`) has a list of contacts :

```
contact_auto_inc      user_id       contact_id
17                       2             7
18                       2             8
19                       2             9
```

I show these contacts, their corresponding names, with this code :

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <?php
         //this code below will get the username of contacts
         // for $user_id. we get the 'contact_id'
         //values in the contacts table for $user_id, match those contact_ids to    the corresponding 
         //'user_ids' in the user table, and then show the 'usernames' for each of those user_ids
           $select_from_user_table = "SELECT  contacts.contact_id, user.username
         FROM contacts 
         INNER JOIN user
         ON contacts.contact_id=user.user_id WHERE contacts.user_id = '$user_id'";

        //get the result of the above
         $result2=mysqli_query($con,$select_from_user_table);

    //show the usernames, phone numbers
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) { ?>
         <input type='checkbox' name='check_contacts[]' value='<?=$row['contact_id']?>'> <?php echo $row['username'] ?> </br>

        <?php } ?>

    <!--<input type="submit" name = "create" value = "Create new Contact"></p> -->

    <!--</form> -->

<p><input type="submit" name = "Save" value = "Save"></p>
<p><input type="submit" name = "Delete" value = "Delete"></p>
<a href="exit.php">Exit</a>
</form>
```

So it looks like this :

[image: image.]

And if one of the boxes is checked and then saved that contact gets saved to a `review_shared` table like this :

```
<?php
//here we want to save the checked contacts to the review_shared table ;  that is,
//who the user wants to share reviews with
if(!empty($_POST['check_contacts'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_contacts'] as $check) {

    $insert_review_shared_command = "INSERT INTO review_shared VALUES(NULL," .$_GET['id']. ", '$user_id','$check')";

        //we want to save the checked contacts into the review_shared table
        $insert_into_review_shared_table = mysqli_query($con,$insert_review_shared_command);

    }

}
$con->close();
?>
```

But whenever I go back to the page, I still see :

[image]

How would I show contacts from the `contacts` table that are also in the `review_shared` table 
with a check in the corresponding check box ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the data from review_shared and compare inside while if matches check else unchecked: Add `checked="checked"` to check-boxes inside while to check it.

```
     <?php
      $review_shared=array(1,2,3,4);//get contact_id in this from shared table
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
        if(in_array($row['contact_id'],$review_shared)){ ?>
             <input type='checkbox' name='check_contacts[]' value='<?=$row['contact_id']?>' checked="checked"> <?php echo $row['username'] ?> </br>
         <?php  }else{?>
        <input type='checkbox' name='check_contacts[]' value='<?=$row['contact_id']?>' > <?php echo $row['username'] ?> </br>           
   <?php }}?>
```

Comment: No it's not all the names that would be checked, just the ones that are in both the contacts table and the review_shared table.

Comment: @ChristopheHarris then first get the data from review_shared and compare inside while if matches check else unchecked .

Comment: Great stuff. Will need to make $review_shared as variables from a Select statement but in principle your code does the job, thanks for your time.